# One grid container per page?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

All grid CSS frameworks have some kind of 'container' class that represents the grid boundaries.

Imagine that I have a page with:

- header
- search form
- search results (loaded dynamically)
- some more dynamic content
- footer

Should (A) I have everything above inside one single grid container (i.e. to have a container per page); or it is (B) better to have each of above parts (i.e. logical parts of the page) to be a separate container, or (C) is is ok to have 3 containers: header, content, footer.

Is there any difference with this approaches or it is just personal choice? I just couldn't find any advice on this topic.

Comment: `Is there any difference [...]` Perhaps, perhaps not. It depends on the layout. Can't say anything more than this.

Comment: OK, but at least statistically someone can tell if he is using one of the approaches more then other. There is always way to be a good engineer, so there is not a reason to close a question.

Comment: Depends on the layout really. If you ever have content that is 100% width and isn't constrained to the container ( such as a banner with a background color that stretches across the page ) you should wrap each individual section.

Comment: Would you like me to provide a JSfiddle with some examples below?

Comment: Does not have to be JSFiddle (dont waste time), but if you can provide an answer with few descriptive IF-THEN examples (like above) of when one approach is used, I would be more then happy with it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the project and what the design requirements are. The "container" class should contain the content, anything that goes outside of that container should not be inside the container div.

Example:

A header that has a background color that stretches 100% of the screen width, but with header elements that are left / right aligned with the container.

The markup would look something like:

```
<header><!-- this would be 100% width -->
 <div class="container></div><!-- this would be whatever your container max-width value is -->
</header>
```